# Get the distinct items from an IEnumerable<T>

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have an `IEnumerable<Person>` object. The `Person` class has a `Designation` property. I want to select distinct `Designation` values from `IEnumerable<Person>` and assign that to a DropDownList. How can I do it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
var designations = persons.Select(p => p.Designation).Distinct();
```